# C# Set string value with " " without printing it

Tags: c#, string, return-value

Full Disclosure: This is a homework assignment. I am not looking for a handout, just guidance because     I am stuck.

I am trying to convert a month and day (both int) into a string representation of "month/day". This is what I have so far.

What I cannot figure out is how to return the date with the "/" between the month and day.

```
    public string toString()  
    {
        string month = myMonth.ToString();
        string day = myDay.ToString();
        string date = month "/" day; // I know this won't work. I just wanted to give a visual of what I want the final result to look like.
        /// so today would be ' 11/11 ' tomorrow ' 11/12 '
        return date;
    }
```

NOTE: this method does not print the result it only creates it.

Comment: are you trying to override the toString() method in your class?

Comment: No I was just utilizing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mihai** is correct but you can also do:-

```
string data = string.Format("{0}/{1}",month,day);
```

which in my opinion looks better

Comment: not just looks better, but good to avoid string concatenations.

Comment: Don't know about that. Usually concatenations are faster than using string.Format.

Answer (score 2):

```
public string toString()  
    {
        return myMonth + "/" + myDay;
    }
```

OR

```
    public string toString()  
    {
        return string.format("{0}/{1}",myMonth,myDay);
    }
```